# Get "the" dialogFragment from a ListView setOnItemClickListener view

Tags: android, listview, android-dialogfragment

Here's one!  You have a ...

```
public class SomePopup extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener
```

it creates a ListView inside itself

```
public ListView happyListView;
public HappyAdapter ourAdaptor;
```

Then inside this ...

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
    ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

.. as usual you set up the list. in this case the user can click on "any row", and do this to it...which is also inside onCreateView...

```
happyListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
      {
      ParseUser chosen = (ParseUser) happyListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
      Utils.Log("YOU CLICKED ON .......... " + .. chosen);

      // actually close this entire DialogFragment
      SOMETHING.dismiss();

      }
    });
```

Notice the SOMETHING.  How do you do that?!

I solved it by calling back to the class which created the DialogFragment and having that instance .dismiss() the DialogFragment.

But how do you get at "this" DialogFragment when you're inside happyListView.setOnItemClickListener?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the class and put the `this` (as the reference to your `SomePopup`) after the class name`SomePopup.this`.. it will only work if `happyListView.setOnItemClickListener` is inside the dialogfragment.. because it is an anonymous class..

**example:**

```
happyListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
  {
  ParseUser chosen = (ParseUser) happyListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
  Utils.Log("YOU CLICKED ON .......... " + .. chosen);

  // actually close this entire DialogFragment
  SomePopup.this.dismiss();

  }
});
```

Comment: That is absolutely amazing, thank you so much.  As an objc programmer I would never have figured that out! :)  When you say it is an **anonymous class**, what are you referring to, Rod?  Do you mean the "new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()", or something else?  THANKS AGAIN

Comment: yes the OnItemClickListener is the anonymous class and if you call just "this" it wont work because it will have the OnItemClickListener reference

Comment: Gotchya.  it's amazing you can say "classname" then "dot this" and it understands you mean the instance, of that classname, "above" us.  freaky and awesome, I love java!  :)  in objc you have to pass in the "this" with a freaky memory management condition and so on.  I will click over a bounty after the time limit allows me to, THANKS AGAIN MAN, REALLY